# What are the ways to extract 8 nibbles in an integer (assuming 32bit integer) in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying a basic Hash-Table program..which is to count number of 1's in an integer:

I have a hash-table which is an array with number of 1's in `0,1,2...E,F`

```
HashTable:
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   1
9   2
A   2
B   3
C   2
D   3
E   3
F   4
```

Now, I want to extract 8 nibbles from integer so that I can use `arr[nibble-value]` to get number of 1's in each nibble.

```
int arr[16] = {0,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4};

int main (void)  
{
    int x = 127;
    int temp, sum =0, i;
    int nibbles = 2 * sizeof(x);
    for (i = 1; i<= nibbles; i++) 
    {
        temp = x << (4*i);   //  <<< I Know this is wrong!!!! <<Here is what I need!!>>
        printf("Temp[%d]:%d\n", i, temp);
        sum = sum + arr[temp];
    }
    printf("No.of ones: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

May be a simple logic...

Comment: BTW, is that your final aim: to get the total number of bits set per nibble?

Comment: I'm just trying basic Hash-table technique, so to answer your question..Yes!

Comment: Btw, the number of set bits is called the "population count" or "popcount". Armed with that search term, you can find a lot of information about other ways to do it, if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the first bit is numbered zero, and so is the first nibble, exactly like array indexes. So by starting the loop from `1` you actually start with the *second* nibble and get the last nibble from *beyond* the integer.

Also, you shift in the wrong direction, and should mask out the top bits, i.e. do

```
for (i = 0; i< nibbles; i++) 
{
    temp = (x >> (4 * i)) & 0x0f;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The change is at the line: `temp = 0xF & (x >> i*4);`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[16] = {0,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4};

int main (void)  
{
     int x = 127;
     int temp, sum =0, i;
     int nibbles = 2 * sizeof(x);
     for (i = 0; i<nibbles; i++) 
     {
         temp = 0xF & (x >> i*4); // I Know this is wrong!!!! <<Here is what I need!!>>
         printf("Temp[%d]:%d\n", i, temp);
         sum = sum + arr[temp];
     }
     printf("No.of ones: %d\n", sum);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's easier to modify existing state and do less (seemingly) work in the body of the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < nibbles; i++, x >>= 4) 
{
    temp = x & 0xf;
    /* ... */
}
```

The above modifies `x` on every loop iteration, so to extract the next nibble we just need to grab the four least significant bits on each iteration. This cuts out the semi-complicated nibble-masking expression, which might be considered making the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
for (i = 0; i<8; i++) 
{

     temp = (x>>(i*4)) & 0xF;
     printf("Temp[%d]:%d\n", i, temp);
     sum += arr[temp];
}
```